Export an existing Histogram with OpenTelemetry
There is an Histogram that I create in my other tool and I would like to export it via OTLP-COLLECTOR, specifically by using OtlpGrpcMetricExporter.
There is an option to create an Histogram value-by-value by using OpenTelemetry's Record(value, context) function, but I don't have the data, I only have the histogram and I prefer not to build it again.
Is there a way to do it or I must build the Histogram from scratch (value-by-value)?
I'm able to pack the Histogram into MetricData and MetricData pack into ScopeMetrics, but I cannot find a way how to export the MetricData or ScopeMetrics by using OtlpGrpcMetricExporter.
I am able to see the ScopeMetrics on the screen by using OStreamMetricExporter, but it is a different exporter.

It would help to include a minimal code sample and which language you're working with.

@MattHensley I have a better one, soon I will share the solution that I found to the problem :)
